# React App's npm i is Hanging on Installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So, I've tried running `npm i` on my React app so that I can work concurrently on both front and back end at the same time.  However, it seems to be hanging on the "install":

```
appName@0.1.0 install
cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
```

Below are the `package.json` scripts I'm using:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified.\" && exit 1",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into an infinite loop since you have defined an `install` script in your `package.json`. For more details on [npm `scripts` configuration have a look here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts).

You might also be facing similar issues with some of the other scripts you have defined, e.g. `build` also calls itself `npm run build`. You should build the project code as part of the `build` script. See the CRA source build script for reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/d960b9e38c062584ff6cfb1a70e1512509a966e7/package.json#L8

Try removing the `install` script and run the commands manually when you need to install dependencies for your project. The updated scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

As a side note/question, why don't you run `npm i` from the root of the project and then run your `build` and `seed` commands?

Only installing dependencies will not build your app, in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, @segFault!  You were right.  I removed the `install` script and `npm i` was able to run.  You were also right about difficulties with the `build` script.  (It was also hanging.)  I updated it to the same code as what you suggested, but I'm getting an error that says "`sh: line 0: cd: packages/react-scripts: No such file or directory`."  Could you please assist? :)

Comment: That I am not sure of. The build itself depends entirely on how you intend to build your JS which is out of scope of this thread. If you used Create React App originally to get started and then [ejected](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) it, `react-scripts` was removed as a dependency. To get started with a custom build setup, have a look at [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: Thanks, @segFault!  I did create the app initially using my terminal and `npx create-react-app`.  When I do that, typically `"build": "cd client && npm run build"` works.  I'll troubleshoot this further and create a new question if needed.  Thanks again!  I appreciate your help.